# Native base Picker Icon is not clickable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

The caret icon of picker in react native base is not responding properly on click. Sometimes on clicking exactly on caret icon , it responds , sometimes it does not .

Comment: Please share the code to understand the issue

Comment: Try to add padding around the component to make the clickable area larger. Also, if you have remote JS debugging enabled, try to test the click after disabling it. Adding some code here is a good idea as well.

Comment: Does this happen on android and ios? What code are you using? You need to compose a better question.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone running into this issue - the problem with me was that I was wrapping my picker inside an Item input field (with the picker prop set to true - as outlined [in the official NativeBase docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-input-headref)) - which was causing the icon caret on Android to be not tappable.

```
import { Item, Picker } from 'native-base';

<Item picker style={styles.picker}>
    <Picker .... />
</Item>
```

Removing this Item input field and replacing it with a View (and applying the appropriate styling) fixed this issue.

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from 'native-base';

<View style={styles.picker}>
    <Picker ... />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
import { Picker,Item } from 'native-base';

<View>
<Item rounded style={[styles.inputStyle, { marginTop: 6 }]}>
      <Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
          placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
          placeholderTextColor="white" 
          placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
          style={[styles.inputmain, {height: 44}]}
          selectedValue={this.state.selected}
          onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
      >
          <Picker.Item label="Select Gender" value=""/>
          <Picker.Item label="Male" value="male"/>
          <Picker.Item label="Female" value="female"/>
          <Picker.Item label="Other" value="other"/>
      </Picker>
 </Item>
 </View>
```

Style:

```
inputStyle: {
    borderColor: "transparent",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    width: Metrics.WIDTH * 0.8
  },
  inputmain: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    paddingTop: 7,
    paddingBottom: 7,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderRadius: 40,
    width: Metrics.WIDTH * 0.8,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(102,102,102,0.6)"
  },
```